# New select column with a counter that increase depending on conditions in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, rank, row-number

I need to create a new column dinamically in SQL with a counter depending on certain conditions

i.e.

```
ID ||| COLUMN1 ||| COLUMN2 ||| COLUMN3 ||| COLUMN 4 |||NEW_COLUMN
1        null        null        null         12    
2         13         null        null         18           1
3        null        null        null         82            
4        null        null        null         81           
5        null        null        31           89           2
6        null        22          32           91           3
7        null        92          null         95           4
```

The counter is going to increase only when COLUMN1 or COLUMN2 or COLUMN 3 != null

The sentence would be something like:

```
SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4, (SELECT .....) FROM ... WHERE ...
```

I don't know if that's possible or if that's the correct way to face this problem in terms of efficiency. Other possibilities are doing that with java or with Jasper Reports, but i think that SQL is the easiest way to do that

Any advise is welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.*, (@row := case 
                     when column1 is not null or column2 is not null or column3 is not null 
                     then @row
                     else null
            end) as NEW_COLUMN,
            (@row := case 
                     when column1 is not null or column2 is not null or column3 is not null 
                     then @row + 1 
                     else @row 
            end) as TEMP_COLUMN
from your_table t, (select @row := 0) r
```

I used a `temp_column` as helper.

Comment: The condition in the `CASE` statement should use `OR` rather than `AND` as they want the counter to increment when any of the first three columns is not null, rather than when all of them are not null.

Comment: Neat :) But given that the calculated value varies depending upon the preceding rows, this query is of questionable value without an explicit order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
select a.ID,a.COLUMN1,a.COLUMN2,a.COLUMN3,a.COLUMN4,COUNT(b.ID) from
(select * from <your_table> where coalesce(column1,column2,column3) is not null)a
join 
(select * from <your_table> where coalesce(column1,column2,column3) is not null)b
on a.ID>=b.ID
group by a.ID,a.COLUMN1,a.COLUMN2,a.COLUMN3,a.COLUMN4 
union all
select *,null from <your_table> where coalesce(column1,column2,column3) is null
order by id
```